Logic For Developer's Profile Model-ROR
So i wanted to make a Profile Model of a user. The association is like

a User has_one Profile

The requirement for this is:

Personal Details: Name, email (optional), contact information, social media links.
Education: Degree, institution, and graduation dates.
Work Experience: Positions, companies, duration, and responsibilities.
other: profile pic, headline, availability for Mentorship, skills

Now i wanted to make a model for it but the problem is that i can't make a logic.
I wanted that it take single entity for name, email, contact, pic, headline, availability etc. but when it comes to Education, work Experience, social media link, it can ask for multiple entity.
like i can enter in Education fields first for school, then for college/university same do this with Work Experience. Enter in Work Experience field for one company then for Other. Can Enter Social Media links for LinkedIn, github etc.
I tried to make a logic where it's migration contains these fields:
It uses serialization concept.
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :email
      t.text :contact_info
      t.text :social_media_links, array: true, default: []
      t.text :education, array: true, default: []
      t.text :work_experience, array: true, default: []
      t.string :profile_picture
      t.string :headline
      t.text :key_skills, array: true, default: []
      t.boolean :availability_for_mentorship, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Is there any other ways to do this thing like using nested forms etc. As I'm beginner so if you guide me which would be better approach and how i can make better logic for this

"Is there any other ways to do this thing" yes, you could use an RDBMS the way it was intended and create new tables and relate them to the profile either directly or indirectly through a join table. As a basic example you could create a skills table that stores known skills and then a profile_skills table that creates a relationship between Profile and Skill as a has_many.

I recommend you not to save data in arrays if you don't must. My suggestion is to create separate models for education, work, and social links. Saving data into arrays has limitations.

Limited flexibility: Arrays are difficult to query, validate, and work with when it comes to complex relationships.
Scalability: If you want to add fields specific to education or work experience in the future, arrays become harder to manage.

A relational approach would be a better solution since it will allow flexibility and maintainability. Instead of using arrays, you can model associations between Profile, Education, WorkExperience, and SocialMediaLink. This would allow you to store multiple records for each, like multiple degrees or job experiences, and is a much more scalable approach.
Migrations
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :email
      t.text :contact_info
      t.string :profile_picture
      t.string :headline
      t.boolean :availability_for_mentorship, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateEducations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :educations do |t|
      t.references :profile, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :degree
      t.string :institution
      t.date :graduation_date

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateWorkExperiences < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :work_experiences do |t|
      t.references :profile, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :position
      t.string :company
      t.date :start_date
      t.date :end_date
      t.text :responsibilities

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateSocialMediaLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :social_media_links do |t|
      t.references :profile, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :platform
      t.string :url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Models
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :educations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :work_experiences, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :social_media_links, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :educations, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :work_experiences, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :social_media_links, allow_destroy: true
end

class Education < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
end

class WorkExperience < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
end

class SocialMediaLink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
end

You can use nested forms to handle the creation of multiple associated records (e.g., education, work experience) in a single form.
In the profiles controller, you would permit nested attributes like this:
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
    @profile.educations.build
    @profile.work_experiences.build
    @profile.social_media_links.build
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(
      :name, :email, :contact_info, :profile_picture, :headline, :availability_for_mentorship,
      educations_attributes: [:id, :degree, :institution, :graduation_date, :_destroy],
      work_experiences_attributes: [:id, :position, :company, :start_date, :end_date, :responsibilities, :_destroy],
      social_media_links_attributes: [:id, :platform, :url, :_destroy]
    )
  end
end

In your profile form view, you can create nested fields for educations, work_experiences, and social_media_links using Rails' fields_for helper:
<%= form_with model: @profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <h3>Education</h3>
  <%= f.fields_for :educations do |edu_form| %>
    <%= edu_form.label :degree %>
    <%= edu_form.text_field :degree %>

    <%= edu_form.label :institution %>
    <%= edu_form.text_field :institution %>

    <%= edu_form.label :graduation_date %>
    <%= edu_form.date_field :graduation_date %>
  <% end %>

  <h3>Work Experience</h3>
  <%= f.fields_for :work_experiences do |work_form| %>
    <%= work_form.label :position %>
    <%= work_form.text_field :position %>

    <%= work_form.label :company %>
    <%= work_form.text_field :company %>

    <%= work_form.label :start_date %>
    <%= work_form.date_field :start_date %>

    <%= work_form.label :end_date %>
    <%= work_form.date_field :end_date %>

    <%= work_form.label :responsibilities %>
    <%= work_form.text_area :responsibilities %>
  <% end %>

  <h3>Social Media Links</h3>
  <%= f.fields_for :social_media_links do |sm_form| %>
    <%= sm_form.label :platform %>
    <%= sm_form.text_field :platform %>

    <%= sm_form.label :url %>
    <%= sm_form.url_field :url %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Create Profile" %>
<% end %>

Benefits of This Approach:

Normalized Data: Each education, work experience, and social media link is stored in its own table, making it easy to query, update, or delete.
Flexibility: You can easily add more fields to Education, WorkExperience, or SocialMediaLink in the future without needing to modify serialized data.
Nested Forms: Rails provides a built-in way to handle nested forms, which simplifies form submissions for associated records.

